# Integrate the "Achievements" drop down with the mobile app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, achievements-dialog

Is there any plans to integrate the "Achievements" drop down with the mobile app? It's the one visual indicator I *really*, **really** miss when using the iOS app.

The only idea I've had as to how to achieve this is to have the current "Inbox" icon serving a dual purpose for both the "Inbox" and "Achievements".. with maybe a green indicator highlighting Achievements, and a red indicator highlighting Inbox messages.

Upon clicking the icon, the user would be able to toggle between a list of "Achievements" and a list of "Inbox" items.

Comment: I'm impressed at how *exactly* you described my mock-up. it's validating :)

Comment: @mhlester; great minds think alike ;).